# Bootstrap - Dropdowns in Chrome not formatting correctly

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I've been working with Bootstrap recently and have been working with the dropdown menus that it includes. I normally work in Chrome, but have had to switch to Edge in this case due to a weird issue with how Chrome is formatting my dropdown menus. Here is an example of the difference.

***Chrome***:

[image]

***Edge***:

[image]

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong, and after searching around I've not seen anyone with the same issue.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Test
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">B</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">C</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check in your console , do you get any error or missing file

Comment: No errors whatsoever. However, another member was able to help. Thanks for helping. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This weird situation happened to me. It is because I used bootstrap 4 but referred bootstrap 3.
Check the difference:

Bootstrap 4

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Page Title</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Test
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">B</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">C</a>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Bootstrap 3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Page Title</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Test
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">B</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">C</a>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know it says not to thank people with comments, but thank you so much! This definitely was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change dropdown-menu to dropdown-content.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Test
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">B</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">C</a>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While Shahidul's answer ended up working for me, I'd like to thank you for the help. :)